# Reference errors after installing VS2012RC

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, assembly-resolution, csc

We use dmake for our build machines and VS2010 for building locally.  Everything worked fine, then I installed VS2012 RC (ultimate).

It's building ok in Visual Studio, although I get a bunch of these warnings:

```
There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" 
and the processor architecture of the reference "MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=x86", "x86". 
This mismatch may cause runtime failures. 
Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, 
or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.
```

However, dmake throws a bunch of error message, and they all look like this:

```
SomeFile.cs(172,16): error CS0433: The type 'System.Windows.Input.ICommand' exists in both
 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.dll' and
 'd:\SomeLocalDirectory\external\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0\PresentationCore.dll'
Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.dll: (Location of symbol related to previous error)
d:\SomeLocalDirectory\external\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0\PresentationCore.dll: (Location of symbol related to previous error)
```

From the error message, you can tell we're using a checked in version of .NET (so that we have a stable test environment among other things), and it seems that the installation of VS2012 has caused VS2010 (or at least the CSC that comes with VS2010) to find additional copies of WPF assemblies.

Anyone else run into this?  I know of a few ways to start hacking at this to fix it, but I'm hoping there is a more straightfoward way to solve this.

Comment: I know Microsoft states that VS 2012 RC can be installed with VS 2010 SP1 but I don't trust it. Did you uninstall VS 2010 first before installing VS 2012 RC? Each time I installed an RC it killed my previous version of VS.

Comment: Where do they state that?  I've learned that .NET 4 and .NET 4.5 can't live side by side.

Comment: Installing Visual Studio Versions Side-by-Side [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) and Visual Studio 2012 RC Compatibility [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747.aspx)

Comment: @JoeBehymer: You seem to have misunderstood what you mean. You can certainly install "both" on the same machine. In your case, why do you have PresentationCore.dll in some other folder? Most people don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to **Repair** the Visual Studio 2010 installation from Program and Features in Control Panel.

Comment: I found an explanation, but no solution.  Turns out, this actually worked for me.  Thank you.